# Compiler says variables declared within compiler directive doesnt exist

Tags: c#, compiler-directives

Suppose I have this code (all in the same class):

```
#if CONDITION
    private static readonly string firstName = "First Name";
#endif

    string GetName(){
#if CONDITION
        return firstName;
#endif
        return "Second Name";
    }
```

It is giving me the error **The name 'firstName' does not exist in the current context** in the function `GetName()`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can't reproduce? https://dotnetfiddle.net/j3D6rw - can you provide a fiddle that does, e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/d4E1Fh (but not that form, for obvious reasons)

Comment: Is the first If Condition always true? If not i guess the firstName is never declared.